# Node.js forever module crashes on list

Tags: node.js

I'm running node v0.10.5 on Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm able to get processes started using the forever module, but as soon as I try to list the processes out, forever crashes with this error/stack trace:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nssocket/node_modules/lazy/lazy.js:211
        for (var i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++) {
                                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Function.<anonymous>     (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nssocket/node_modules/lazy/lazy.js:211:38)
    at Lazy.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nssocket/node_modules/lazy/lazy.js:187:21)
    at Lazy.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nssocket/node_modules/lazy/lazy.js:50:22)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:392:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:388:5)
    at Socket.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:250:5)
    at Socket.onSocketEnd (net.js:256:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
```

I've tried upgrading it, and outright reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

It's fixed. And i think will be released soon.

https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/issues/408

or you can patch lazy.js manually

http://cl.ly/code/2k1I3A2r2v0k

Answer (score 1):

Forever is still broken on node.js version 0.10. You install 0.8 via [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for now